# How To Zip Folder With Password Protected Using Gradle Build Tool

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Hi I have looked Around **Gradle** to Zipping Folder With Password Protection.
But I don't find any solution over the **Gradle** API.

I neeed to Zip the folder with password protected using gradle.

Please Suggest solutions .

Answer (score 1):

You can executes a command line process to create a zip with password:

```
task encodeZip(type: Exec) {
    workingDir path_target
    commandLine "zip", "-P", "password", "-r", "myZipFile.zip", "file1", "file2", "file3" 
}
```

**Update:**
`zip` command is available in Linux but there is no `zip` command and any other replacement in Window to zip files with password.

As a work around, you can use a third party utility like 7-Zip command Line version as follow:

```
task encodeZip(type: Exec) {
    workingDir path_target
    commandLine "7za", "a", "-t7z", "myZipFile.zip", "-ppassword", "file1", "file2", "file3" 
}
```

Comment: task encodeZip(type: Exec) {
    workingDir 'ZipFolderWithPassword/'
    commandLine "zip", "-P", "ajay", "-r", "myZipFile.zip", "FirstJavaGradle.jar"
}

I execute this task in windows machine It's raising error 





FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':encodeZip'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'zip''


BUILD FAILED

Comment: Can you run `zip, -P ajay -r myZipFile.zip FirstJavaGradle.jar` in command line? What is your environment?

Comment: Windows 8.1 (64 bit) , jdk 1.7 , gradle 2.14

Comment: Windows do not have a `zip` command and a 3rd party utility is needed. I update the answer and see whether can help